# Finding the smallest index such that the indexed log file does not exist in a particular directory

Tags: command-line, filenames

**Question:** Suppose there is a folder with files `log1.txt, log2.txt, log3.txt, etc`. I would like to find the smallest integer N such that `log<N>.txt` does not exist. Is there a simple command/way to achieve this?

**Example:** if the folder is empty, the command should return `log1.txt`. If the folder has `log1.txt, log2.txt`, the command should return `log3.txt`.

Comment: in the example that you gave, the smallest missing integer is `0` .... i think that you want `next smallest integer`

Comment: Sure. Either definition works for my question (positive or non-negative integers).

Comment: The "_that does not exist_" should apply to the file rather than to the folder. So perhaps "Find lowest numbered file name that does not exist in a folder".

Comment: I've made a suggestion for a new title; feel free to further reword it to make it clearer to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while [ -f "log${i}.txt" ]; do
  ((i++))
done
echo "log${i}.txt"
```

The while-loop increments variable `$i` as long as file `log${i}.txt` exists. The `echo` outputs the non-existing filename with the next number.

Comment: Very nice. It skirts the question a bit, but even `touch log$((i++)).txt` will work for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This horrible pipeline will satisfy your requirement (concatenate the non-comment parts together to create an unreadable one-liner if you must).

Set up

```
touch log{1..13}.txt log{15..20}.txt
```

Find the first available item placement

```
( find log*.txt | sort -V; echo X ) |     # List the files and an extra one at the end
    nl |                                  # Add line-numbers
    tr -dc '[:digit:][:space:]' |         # Strip away non-numeric parts
    sed -r '/ ([1-9][0-9]*)\t\1$/d' |     # Delete lines with two matching numbers
    awk '{print $1; exit}'                # Print the the line number of the first remaining match
```

Output

```
14
```

If you then fill in the missing slot

```
touch log14.txt
```

Output

```
21
```

---

<sub>As an aside for other readers, if you can find a way to improve upon the `tr | sed | awk` construct, which is often indicative of a poorly written pipeline, I'd be interested to see what you suggest.</sub>

Comment: It's a one-liner, can't argue with that :) gj

Comment: "*if you can find a way to improve upon the `tr | sed | awk` construct [...]*": how about `echo $(($(grep -Ec '([1-9][0-9]*)[[:blank:]]+[[:graph:]]+\1\.[[:graph:]]+$') + 1))` ? However, if you ended up using `awk` anyway, why not do everything with it and get rid of `nl` too ? your same algorithm (which I think it's clean and clever) might be like: `awk -F '[^0-9]+' -- 'NR != $(NF-1) {print NR; exit}'` ?